# Injecting Current USer using Structuremap Custom Instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, structuremap, n-tier-architecture

Here is what I am trying to do:
I have implemented Form Authentication in ASP.NET MVC. I have IUser Interface which conforms to IPrincipal (System.Security.Principal). The custom IUser have additional properties  and can be considered as a DTO. I need to use this user in different layers.

Currently my base controller checks whether the form is Authenticated and reconstructs the IUser as in Code[1](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/InstanceExpression.htm#section11). I am passing this current User to Service Layer, which passes them to domain layer and then it gets to Events and Event Handlers( domain events).

All layers are Interface based and StructureMap is used as IoC.
My IoC  is a separate class Library.

I am looking for a way to avaoiding pass user information to each and every method. I found that I could inject Custom Instance of a class as described in link  http://structuremap.net/structuremap/InstanceExpression.htm#section11

I plan to create a Method

```
public void SetCurrentUser(IUser user)
{
    // Something Similart to below ( Below code may be wrong)

    //For<IUser>().TheDefault.IsThis(user);

}
```

and

have  IUser in all class constructors which needs to know about current user

Questions

1) is this a right way to pass User Information to all layers  and do you think it will work.

2) Is this safe, Can a user in one session be hijacked  from another session?

Thank you,

Mar

**Code(1)**

```
string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
// Create a new Generic Principal Instance and assign to Current User
IUser _currentUser= new User
{
    IsApplicationUser = Convert.ToBoolean(roles[0].ToString()),
    Role = (UserRole)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserRole), roles[1].ToString()),
    Id = new Guid(ticket.Name),
    Email = roles[3].ToString(),
    Name = roles[2].ToString(),
    CompanyName = roles[4].ToString(),
    DealerId = roles[5].ToString(),
    LocationId  = roles[6].ToString()
};
```

Comment: I was able to test successfully using Joshua Flanagan suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For<IUser>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use( container => {
    buildUserInstanceFromThreadCurrentPrincipal();
});
```

Comment: @Joshua- Wow never knew something like buildUserInstanceFromThreadCurrentPrincipal() even existed. Thank you. I will try this out today.

Comment: @Joshua- :-) Jumped too quickly to comment. I First thought that buildUserInstanceFromThreadCurrentPrincipal() is a framework method.

Comment: @Joshua- I am calling my IoC Library which calls init on all registry modules in different projects.  What is the earliest life cycle event where  I can place  call to the above code? I  think if I place it in Request Authentication then it will be called for each and every request, base controller still seems to be the best place. Any suggestions?

Comment: @TheMar - the registration code is usually put in Application_Start, since it should only run once.